# Smartest way to increment an int list like a decimal

Tags: java, java-11

I have a list which looks like it: `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. The size is known and fixed.

I'd like to increment the list this way:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
...
[9, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
...
[9, 9, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
...
[9, 9, 9, 9]
```

What is the most optimal way to do it? I've build this function but I guess it could be improved :

```java
private static void incr(List<Integer> list) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean stop = false;
    while (i < list.size() && !stop) {
        if (list.get(i) < 9) {
            list.set(i, list.get(i) + 1);
            stop = true;
        } else {
            list.set(i, 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "like a decimal" but decimal numbers include 0. You don't have any 0s in your list. So it's more like base-9 than decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Replace your "stop" with a "break;" statement.
- then you can also use a for loop, so you don't need to define i seperately beforehand.

Not really better but a bit shorter.

```
private static void incr(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i=0; i <list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) < 9) {
            list.set(i, list.get(i) + 1);
            break;
        }
        list.set(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: (You can still use a for loop, even with the boolean: `boolean stop = false; for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && !stop;)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a small list, so what you have is essentially fine.

The only issue you might encounter on "large" non-`RandomAccess` lists would be the repeated access of the `i`-th element.

You could pull out the `list.get(i)`s to a variable, so you only have to invoke it once per iteration. Mind you, you only invoke it twice on the last iteration, so this is essentially irrelevant.

You could use a `ListIterator`, which can be efficient on all list implementations, even non-`RandomAccess` ones such as `LinkedList`:

```
for (ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  int value = it.next();
  if (value < 9) {
    it.set(value + 1);
    break;
  }

  it.set(1);
}
```

But just to reiterate: what you have already is *almost certainly* fine.